# How to cache expensive async tasks to await those already in-progress?

Tags: caching, rust, rust-tokio

I have a forward cache which computes some expensive values. In some cases I have to perform an expensive call to the same resource. In a situation where the forward cache is already computing the value, I'd like to `.await` until this in-flight computation has completed.

My current (simplified) code is structured similar to this:

```
struct MyStruct {
    cache: Cache, // cache for results
}

impl MyStruct {
    async fn compute(&self) -> ExpensiveThing { ... }

    async fn forward_cache_compute(&self, identifier: &str) {
        // do some expensive computation and cache it:
        ... 
        let value = self.compute().await // .... takes 100 ms ...
        self.cache.insert(identifier, value) 
        // consider if possible to save a future of compute() or conditional variable to wait upon for "identifier"
    }

    async fn get_from_cache_or_compute_if_neeeded(&self, identifier: &str) -> ExpensiveThing {
        // would like to check if the forward cache is already computing and return that value if possible (share a future?)
        if let Some(cached_value) = self.cache.get(identifier) {
            // use this cached_value and don't compute
        } else if ... inflight computation is in progress... {
            // block on that 
            // can I save the future and await it from multiple places?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no silver bullet either you sometime compute twice, either you need a state to manage what you are currently computing or you only compute on item at the time

Answer (score 0):

Here is a poor-man's implementation of an asynchronous cache:

```toml
# Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
async-once-cell = { version = "0.4.2", features = ["unpin"] }
tokio = { version = "1.21.0", features = ["full"] }
```

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::{Mutex, Arc};

use async_once_cell::unpin::Lazy;

struct MyStruct {
    cache: Mutex<HashMap<&'static str, Arc<Lazy<i32>>>>,
}

impl MyStruct {
    async fn get_or_compute(&self, key: &'static str) -> i32 {
        let fut = self
            .cache
            .lock()
            .unwrap()
            .entry(key)
            .or_insert_with(|| Arc::new(Lazy::new(Box::pin(async move {
                println!("calculating value for: {}", key);
                tokio::time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
                1
            }))))
            .clone();

        *fut.get().await
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let my_struct = MyStruct { cache: Default::default() };

    tokio::join![
        my_struct.get_or_compute("a"),
        my_struct.get_or_compute("a"),
        my_struct.get_or_compute("b"),
        my_struct.get_or_compute("b"),
        my_struct.get_or_compute("c"),
        my_struct.get_or_compute("a"),
        my_struct.get_or_compute("b"),
    ];
}
```

```
calculating value for: a
calculating value for: b
calculating value for: c
```

As you can see, `.get_or_compute()` is called multiple times for the same keys concurrently but the task is only executed once for each. The secret sauce is provided by [`Lazy`](https://docs.rs/async-once-cell/0.4.2/async_once_cell/unpin/struct.Lazy.html) from the [async-once-cell](https://crates.io/crates/async-once-cell) crate; it represents a `Future` that can be `.await`-d from multiple places, but will only execute once.